# Magento 2 index management system error message

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, cron, indexer

I installed magento 2.1.9 on my shared hosting account. A system error message appears within the admin panel that states: "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."

Below is a screenshot of the cron jobs I have:

[image]

Any idea if anything is wrong with my cron job? And how can I fix this issue within cPanel's cron job, without having to mess with command line?

An Update:
Today my hosting provider informed me that I cannot be given SSH login details, since I'm on shared hosting environment. What is the way to update the indexer manually on a shared hosting environment, without SSH access?

Comment: Can you please check the commands add in Cpanel, are working on manaual running?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sorry, I cannot check manually, since I don't have the SSH login details to gain access.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up cron for reindexing like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php [path_to_document_root]/bin/magento indexer:reindex >> [path_to_document_root]/var/log/indexer.cron.log
```

Where:

> *** * * * *** - time
>
> **/usr/bin/php** - path to the php

Edit: If you don't know where the PHP binary exists on the server, you can use these commands to know the path of PHP:

> which php

or

> whereis php

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I will try it and see if it works, and then get back to you.

Comment: the cron job is not working

Comment: the issue persists. Please, do you have any other idea how I can fix this on a shared hosting environment, since I don't have SSH login details to run any command?